# the site will not accept my posts

Tags: discussion

Sorry the question is not about Biology because I have not been able to post a question or a comment. I write them out but there is some tech thing that is preventing acceptance. Please advise how I can contact you. user:35281

Comment: Ask this on meta.biology.stackexchange.com or meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also, once you ask your question on meta.biology.stackexchange.com, make sure to specify what is the error message you are receiving.

Comment: At the moment it is not possible to help you without further information.

Answer (score 4):

New users cannot post comments, but can post questions and answers (this caught me up too, since comments seemed so minor compared to a question or answer).

You should be able to post a question by clicking the "Ask Question" button in the upper right of the home Biology page.